# Image quality from my android app is saving in very low pixels - android studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, camera

I am building a camera app but when I take the pictures it is coming out in very low quality.

Below is my code for my MyCameraActivity.java

I cannot seem to improve the quality and I have went through the other solutions on this site and they dont seem to work for me.

The quality is about 177 x 144 pixels and my phone is capable of 3mp.

```
package com.laveshpillay.laveshcamera;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mycamera.R;

public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {

// Use constants above API 11 (MediaStore.Files.FileColumns)
protected static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 0;
protected static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ = 100;
private static final String TAG = "MCAct";

private Uri fileUri;
private Camera camera;
private CameraPreview preview;
private MediaRecorder mr;
private Button videoButton;
protected boolean isRecording = false;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!checkCameraExists(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry: you have no camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        finish();
    }
    camera = getCameraInstance();
    setUpLayout();
}

// Method required if setting up an Intent button
// to call the built-in camera
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // A known bug here! The image should have saved in fileUri
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully in: "
                        + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the operation; do nothing
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Callout for image capture failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    releaseCamera();
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = getCameraInstance();
        setUpLayout();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

protected Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}


protected boolean prepareForVideoRecording() {
    camera.unlock();
    mr = new MediaRecorder();
    mr.setCamera(camera);
    mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mr.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mr.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
    mr.setPreviewDisplay(preview.getHolder().getSurface());
    try {
        mr.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException when preparing MediaRecorder "
                + e.getMessage());
        e.getStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException when preparing MediaRecorder "
                + e.getMessage());
        e.getStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean checkCameraExists(Context c) {
    if (c.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No camera: exception " + e.getMessage());
        e.getStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry: I can't get a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        finish();
    }
    return c;
}

private void getImage() {
    PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
            new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    };
    camera.takePicture(null, null, picture);

}

private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // good location for shared pictures; will not be lost if app uninstalled
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getPackageName());
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
            return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File file;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        file = new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"
                + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        file = new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_"
                + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return file;
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        preview = null;
    }
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
    if (mr != null) {
        mr.reset();
        mr.release();
        mr = null;
        camera.lock();
    }
}

private void setUpLayout() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    frame.addView(preview);

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getImage();
                }
            }
    );
    setUpFlashButton();
    setUpIntentButton();
    setUpVideoButton();
}

private void setUpFlashButton() {
    final Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    final List<String> flashList = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
    if (flashList == null) {
        // no flash!
        return;
    }
    final CharSequence[] flashCS = flashList.toArray(
            new CharSequence[flashList.size()]);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose flash type");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(flashCS, -1,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    params.setFlashMode(flashList.get(which));
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), params.getFlashMode(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    Button flashButton = new Button(this);
    setUpButton(flashButton, "Flash");
    flashButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
    );
}

private void setUpIntentButton() {
    Button intentButton = new Button(this);
    setUpButton(intentButton, "Built-in");
    intentButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                    Log.v(TAG, "fileUri: " + fileUri);
                    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                    startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ);
                }
            }
    );
}

private void setUpVideoButton() {
    videoButton = new Button(this);
    setUpButton(videoButton, "Video");

    videoButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isRecording) {
                        mr.stop();
                        releaseMediaRecorder();
                        camera.lock();
                        videoButton.setText("Start video");
                        isRecording = false;
                    } else {
                        if (prepareForVideoRecording()) {
                            mr.start();
                            videoButton.setText("Stop video");
                            isRecording = true;
                        } else {
                            // Something has gone wrong! Release the camera
                            releaseMediaRecorder();
                            Toast.makeText(MyCameraActivity.this,
                                    "Sorry: couldn't start video",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}

private void setUpButton(Button button, String label) {
    LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
    button.setText(label);
    button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lin.addView(button);
}



class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
        File picFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (picFile == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating media file; are storage permissions correct?");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
            fos.write(data[0]);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "I/O error with file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

PS. If anyone can help me change the images to show in my gallery as well i would appreciate it.

And just so that you know. I'm really new to Android Development

Answer (score 0):

Check this class. Call getPickImageIntent to create chooser intent and when you recieve your result call to getImageFromResult.

The class:
https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately it doesnt seem to help